# How Can I call my plugin controller in Zend?

Tags: zend-framework

I try to create a "plugin controller" in zend framework.
My problem ... I can not know "where" to save it or how load it.

The architecture of my site is like this:

```
/ application
-----/admin
-----/default
----------/controllers
---------------/plugins
----------/models
----------/views
/ library
-----/Zend
```

I called my plugin "Default_Controller_Plugin_Language" and have saved in `/ application / default / controllers / plugins`

```
class Default_Controller_Plugin_Language
extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
{[...]
```

I tried to load it into my bootstrap, but he said that the file was not found.

```
protected function _initLanguage()
{
    $front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
    $front->registerPlugin(new Default_Controller_Plugin_Language());
}
```

Where should I place my file and then how do I specify its location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was that I forget the namespace in the `initAutoloader`.